# VirtualBox with Host-Only network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, osx-mountain-lion

There is no explicit network group, so apologies if my question does belong in a different forum...

I have couple of laptops. One of which is old Mac with 20.8 on it.

Unfortunately it the only one I can dedicate to do what I want.

I'd like to make a VM on the VirtualBox and set up old version of Debian on it.

Google gave me a version of VB 5
0.40 (latest I can run on this OS).

I grabbed it and successfully installed it and then tried to create VM.

VM was made successfully, but trying to set Host-Only Network failed, because there is no menu option to set the interface up.

In fact no other possibilities are available.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Does this work?   https://carleton.ca/scs/2019/creating-a-new-host-only-adapter-in-virtualbox/#:~:text=Setting%20Up%20a%20Virtual%20Host%2Donly%20Network,-Before%20you%20can&text=On%20the%20main%20VirtualBox%20window,side%20of%20the%20network%20details.    ...  If not, your version of VBOX may be too old and you would have to try a different host machine.

Comment: This sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363652/virtualbox-missing-add-host-only-network-option

Comment: @John, no it isn't.  There is no `Host Network Manager` there as I already said in the OP. You are not thorough... 

Comment: @Gantendo, yes, it is. And just like Rohit, I don't have either options. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need a newer host for newer VBOX that does include the option.

Comment: @John, thx. Will see what can I do.